# Oracle SQL: Joining same table and getting desired output

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a table like this

```
FILEID    | FILENAME               | STATUS
100       |Employee_06102016.txt   |PASS
100       |Employee_06092016.txt   |FAIL
100       |Employee_06092016.txt   |MISS
101       |ABC_06092016.txt        |PASS
```

I am reading a filename from file and passing to SQL. Lets say, i have only the  file name 'Emplyee_06102016.txt' which is with PASS staus. With this, i need to join the same table and take the count of PASS and FAIL filenames which have same file id and should exclude the MISS status.

I am trying something like this below but gives count as 3 including all. I should get only 2.

```
SELECT COUNT (T.FILEID)  FROM TABLE_NAME T, TABLE_NAME S
WHERE T.FILEID=S.FILEID
AND T.FILENAME = 'Employee_06102016.txt' AND T.STATUS IN ('PASS', 'FAIL');
```

Comment: Why do you need to join the same table again?

Comment: I need to take count of PASS & FAIL status which has same fileid. I have only filename of one record. so i should join right?

Comment: `Select FileName, count(t.status) 
from Table_name t
where t.fileName = 'Employee_06102016.txt' and Status <> 'FAIL' Group by FileName`  The reason your failing is because (if you need the self join) you need to only include s.status of ('PASS','FAIL') as well.  otherwise you get a join to the fail record causing you to get 3 records instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( FILEID, FILENAME, STATUS ) AS
SELECT 100, 'Employee_06102016.txt', 'PASS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'Employee_06092016.txt', 'FAIL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'Employee_06092016.txt', 'MISS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'ABC_06092016.txt',      'PASS' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY FileID ) AS num_pass_fail
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  status IN ( 'PASS', 'FAIL' )
)
WHERE  filename = 'Employee_06102016.txt';
```

**Output**:

```
    FILEID FILENAME              STATUS NUM_PASS_FAIL
---------- --------------------- ------ -------------
       100 Employee_06102016.txt PASS               2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   FILENAME,
   SUM(CASE status WHEN 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Pass Count",
   SUM(CASE status WHEN 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Fail Count",
   SUM(CASE status WHEN 'MISS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Miss Count"
FROM
   TableName
WHERE
   FILENAME = 'Employee_06102016.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you..I tried this and it gives only passcount as 1 and other 2 as zero.. because filename varies in all. My requirement is, i have filename. I need to check for all filenames, which is having the same fileid (100 in this case) and check how many records are there. Expected output count is 2 for me..(i take Employee_06102016.txt and get 100 as file id. Under 100 file id , there is one pass and one fail)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you simply need:

```
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FILENAME = 'Employee_06102016.txt'
  AND STATUS IN ('PASS', 'FAIL');
```

Comment: Returns a count of 1 - the OP is expecting a count of 2 (as there are 2 rows with the same `FileID`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select cnt from ( 
    select count(*) as cnt, 
      listagg(filename, ',') within group(order by filename) as filename_list  from table_name 
     where status in ('PASS', 'FAIL') group by fileid
 ) where instr(filename_list, 'Employee_06102016.txt')>0;
```

Comment: What happens if you have a file named `'Not_Employee_06102016.txt'`?